# Dividing images and the text for each image correctly

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a product page , a simple one, but I'm having problems dividing the images and the text for each image correctly , I took a screenshot where I illustrate what happens and what I want to do.

**Code (HTML):**

```
 <h1 style="color:#e68a00">Zona de produtos.</h1>
  <p style="color:#0080ff">Os melhores equipamentos aos melhores preços.</p>

    <div class="uk-grid">
      <div class="uk-width-1-3"><img src="/productimages/xxx1"></div>
      <div class="uk-width-1-3"><img src="/productimages/xxx2"></div>
      <div class="uk-width-1-3"><img src="/productimages/xxx3"></div>
      <br><br>
      <div class="uk-grid">
        <div class="uk-width-1-3"><h2>iPhone X 64GB</h2></div>
        <div class="uk-width-1-3"><h2> HP Pavilion</h2></div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

**Here's what i meant to do**

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The "uk-grid" and "uk-width" class is part of UIKIT tool you can check it out here https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/grid.html (i'm not using my custom css on this page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this !!!

```
<div style="text-align:center">
    <h1 style="color:#e68a00">Zona de produtos.</h1>
      <p style="color:#0080ff">Os melhores equipamentos aos melhores preços.</p>

        <div class="uk-grid">
          <div class="uk-width-1-3" ><img src="/productimages/xxx1">
          <h2>iPhone X 64GB</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="uk-width-1-3" ><img src="/productimages/xxx2">
          <h2> HP Pavilion</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="uk-width-1-3" ><img src="/productimages/xxx3"></div>
    </div>`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to move the text to the div which is holding the image and then set the positions and alignment as per your requirements.

```html
<h1 style="color:#e68a00">Zona de produtos.</h1>
  <p style="color:#0080ff">Os melhores equipamentos aos melhores preços.</p>

    <div class="uk-grid">
      <div class="uk-width-1-3" style="text-align:center;"><img src="/productimages/xxx1">
      <h2>iPhone X 64GB</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-width-1-3" style="text-align:center;"><img src="/productimages/xxx2">
      <h2> HP Pavilion</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="uk-width-1-3"><img src="/productimages/xxx3"></div>
```

Comment: Yea , that helps a bit , thanks bud , if i want to center the text with each image , would i be able to do it the same way?

Comment: have updated the answer with details on how to align the text. please check the style property to align the text center to the div. You can even try to use a table and fit the images in a table row, but for large pages the table on html is not performant.

Comment: you should have atleast upvoted this answer, since the one you marked as answer is same as what i posted.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```css
.uk-width-1-3 img{
  width: 100%;
}
.uk-grid {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.uk-width-1-3 {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 style="color:#e68a00">Zona de produtos.</h1>
<p style="color:#0080ff">Os melhores equipamentos aos melhores preços.</p>

<div class="uk-grid">
  <div class="uk-width-1-3">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg">
    <h2>iPhone X 64GB</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-width-1-3">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg">
    <h2> HP Pavilion</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="uk-width-1-3">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg">
    <h2> HP Pavilion</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would also move the image and the text into one div as @Eby Jacob mentioned. Then you could use the flex layout which does a good job in handling the widths.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <style>
         .container{
            display: flex;
         }

         .container > div {
            flex: 1; /* The weight of the div */
            padding: 10px;
         }

         .productTitle {
            text-align:center;
         }

         .productDescription{
            text-align: justify;
            text-justify: inter-word;
         }         
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>

      <div class="container">
         <div >
            <img src="Computer.jpg" alt="Product Image"/>
            <h2 class="productTitle">Product title 1</h2>
            <p class="productDescription">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut at ipsum vehicula, porta diam lobortis, vulputate lacus. Sed neque nunc, luctus vitae lorem vitae, pellentesque sodales arcu.
            </p>
         </div>

         <div class="product">
            <img src="Computer.jpg" alt="Product Image"/>
            <h2 class="productTitle">Product title 2</h2>
            <p class="productDescription">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut at ipsum vehicula, porta diam lobortis, vulputate lacus. Sed neque nunc, luctus vitae lorem vitae, pellentesque sodales arcu.
            </p>
         </div>

         <div class="product">
            <img src="Computer.jpg" alt="Product Image"/>
            <h2 class="productTitle">Product title 3</h2>
            <p class="productDescription">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut at ipsum vehicula, porta diam lobortis, vulputate lacus. Sed neque nunc, luctus vitae lorem vitae, pellentesque sodales arcu.
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```